# converting a space delimited file to a CSV

Tags: python

I have a text file containing tabular data.  What I need to do is automate the task of writing to a new text file that is comma delimited instead of space delimited, extract a few columns from existing data, reorder the columns.

This is a snippet of the first 4 lines of the original data:

```
Number of rows: 8542
 Algorithm  |Date   |Time   |Longitude  |Latitude   |Country    
 1  2000-01-03  215926.688  -0.262  35.813  Algeria 
 1  2000-01-03  215926.828  -0.284  35.817  Algeria
```

Here is what I want in the end:

```
Longitude,Latitude,Country,Date,Time
-0.262,35.813,Algeria,2000-01-03,215926.688
```

Any tips on how to approach this?

Comment: There was something wrong with how you presented your snippet, I believe it's what you intended.

Comment: Yes the order is important.  the latitude/longitude fields need to be the first two columns in the new output

Comment: Seems like the OP can't join the chat until he has 20 reputation... How can I donate him some?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the file is separated by tabs, not spaces.

If so, you can try something like:

```
input_file = open('some_tab_separated_file.txt', 'r')
output_file = open('some_tab_separated_file.csv', 'w')
input_file.readline() # skip first line 
for line in input_file:
    (a, date, time, lon, lat, country) = line.strip().split('\t')
    output_file.write(','.join([lon, lat, country, date, time]) + '\n')
input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

This code is untested, any bug is left for you as exercise.

Comment: Hi, it looks like this would reorder the field header names.  Will it also reorder the data in the columns or is there another step?

Comment: providing its tab-separated, should reorder header and data inside a `for line in file` loop.

Comment: Still working on your method.  Getting this: "failed to run script - syntax error - can't assign to literal"  Changed all the field names to the correct name.

Comment: Could you join me at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6712/paulos ?? I will help you.

Comment: Paulo - I have to have a "reputation" of 20 to use the chat room. the reply function is disabled.  Am at 13 now

Comment: ok, I'm having trouble with the 5th line.  I'm replacing the field names that you have provided in the above code, but get a syntax error. 
Here is the line:
    (Algorithm, |Date, |Time, |Longitude, |Latitude, |Country, |Continent, |Region, |Admin, |GlobCover, |Biomass, |Koeppen) = line.split('\t')

Comment: That did it!  Your code did the trick.  Thank You!!  -so what is the "|" character for in this example?

Comment: I think "|" in python is the bitwise "or" operator, so you cant use it in variable names.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for sharing your knowledge, this has been a great experience and resource.

Comment: @MLau: I hope you increase your reputation soon in order to be able to use the chat. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `csv` module and a reader with the `' '` delimiter to read your data in, and use the a writer from the same module (with a comma delimiter) to produce the output.

In fact, [the first example in the `csv` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader) uses `delimiter=' '`.

You can use a `DictReader`/`DictWriter` and specify the order of the columns in its constructor (`fieldnames` list: different for reader/writer if you want to re-order) to output the entries in the order you wish.

(You may need to skip/ignore your first two rows when producing the output.)

**EDIT:**

Here is an example for dealing with multi-word country names:

```
import cStringIO
import csv

f = cStringIO.StringIO("""A B C
1 2 Costa Rica
3 4 Democratic Republic of the Congo
""")

r = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=' ', restkey='rest')
for row in r:
    if row.get('rest'):
        row['C'] += " %s" % (" ".join(row['rest']))
    print 'A: %s, B: %s, C: %s' % (row['A'], row['B'], row['C'])
```

Use the `restkey=` and concatenate the dict entry for that value, which is a list of what's left over (here `restkey='rest'`). This prints:

```
A: 1, B: 2, C: Costa Rica
A: 3, B: 4, C: Democratic Republic of the Congo
```

Comment: What happens with a country like "Costa Rica" if you use `delimiter=' '`?

Comment: @PauloScardine, you should be able to use the `restkey` for this (see update). Of course, in the initial example, this will require a bit of clean up with the initial two row, but even when using a plain (non `DictReader`), it should be possible to obtain what's left and join it together.

Answer (score 0):

`str.split()` without any arguments will split by any length of whitespace. `operator.itemgetter()` takes multiple arguments, and will return a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the important idea is that you have to use '\t' as the delimiter @Paulo Scardine.

I just wanted to add that pandas is a very good library for handling column data.

```
>>> src = 'path/to/file'
>>> dest = 'path/to/dest_csv'
>>> column_names = ['names', 'of', 'columns']

>>> df = pd.read_csv(src, delimiter='\t', names=column_names)

# Do something in pandas if you need to

>>> df.to_csv(dest, index=False, sep = ';')
```